# Как делать коммиты от имени аккаунта GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Я создаю репозиторий через аккаунт `GitHub`. Далее я подключаю его с помощью `git remote`. После этого я пушу изменения. Затем захожу на GitHub и вижу, что коммиты были сделаны от "Пётр Петрович", допустим, а не от **имени моего аккаунта**.

В `git config --list` в поле `user.name` как раз и прописан "Пётр Петрович". Если изменить `user.name` на имя аккаунта, будет и на `GitHub` показываться другое имя при коммитах, но всё равно коммиты будут **не** от имени аккаунта GitHub

Пользуюсь `PHPStorm`. Он подключен к моему аккаунту с помощью `GitHub` токена.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git

Comment: @KoVadim Вы хотите сказать, что если я введу в поле `user.name` в `git config` имя своего аккаунт GitHub, все коммиты будут производиться  от него?

Comment: Да, там можно почти что угодно написать

Comment: @KoVadim, мне важно чтобы **от имени аккаунта** коммиты делались, а не просто коммит с моим именем. `git config user.name` изменяет имя, но не возможность делать коммититы  **от имени аккаунта**

Comment: Там рядом email, но об этом уже написали ниже.

Comment: Вторая версия книги: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Введение-Первоначальная-настройка-Git

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[GitHub использует email адрес для ассоциации отправленных коммитов с аккаунтом GitHub.](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/)

Чтобы связать коммиты с аккаунтом GitHub:

- убедитесь, что какой-нибудь email привязан к аккаунту GitHub, в [настройках аккаунта](https://github.com/settings/emails);
- установите **тот же самый** email в настройках Git или репозитория:

  ```
  git config --global user.email "ваш-github-email@example.com"
  ```
- создайте какие-нибудь коммиты (`git commit`) и отправьте их (`git push`) в GitHub.

После этого GitHub признает вас, и все новые коммиты будут подписаны вашим аккаунтом со ссылкой на него, а не просто именем.

Настройка `user.name` при этом никакого значения не имеет. (Хотя я рекомендую сделать имя совпадающим с именем аккаунта на GitHub, чтобы не плодить лишних сущностей.)

[image]

Comment: Видимо что-то поменяли, сейчас так сделать гитхаб мне не позволяет, пишет: push declined due to email privacy restrictions.

Comment: @Fein https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378060

Answer (score 4):

[Руководство по Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git#%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F):

> **Имя пользователя**
>
> Первое, что вам следует сделать после установки Git'а, — указать ваше
>   имя и адрес электронной почты. Это важно, потому что каждый коммит в
>   Git'е содержит эту информацию, и она включена в коммиты, передаваемые
>   вами, и не может быть далее изменена:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
> $ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
> ```
>
> Повторюсь, что, если указана опция `--global`, то эти настройки
>   достаточно сделать только один раз, поскольку в этом случае Git будет
>   использовать эти данные для всего, что вы делаете в этой системе. Если
>   для каких-то отдельных проектов вы хотите указать другое имя или
>   электронную почту, можно выполнить эту же команду без параметра
>   `--global` в каталоге с нужным проектом.

Идентификатором аккаунта на гитхабе является имейл, поэтому, чтобы исправить аккаунт, с которого приходят коммиты, нужно изменить в настройках имейл командой `git config --global user.email` для всех проектов сразу или `git config user.email` для отдельного проекта.

Comment: мне важно чтобы **от имени аккаунта** коммиты делались, а не просто коммит с моим именем. `git config user.name` изменяет имя, но не возможность делать коммититы от имени аккаунта

Comment: @ВладЖадченко если user.email будет совпадать с тем email, который привязан к гитхабу, то коммиты будут от имени аккаунта

Comment: ``git config user.email``

Comment: Спасибо, при изменении `git config user.email` на тот, который указан на `GitHub`, коммиты от имени аккаунта работают!