# Почему я в своем проекте являюсь contributor?

Tags: git

Такая ситуация: в проекте, который я закомитил с другого компа я сам оказываюсь во вкладке `contributors` на `GitHub`, а если все коммиты с одного компа, то в контрибьюторах меня нет - почему? Вот пример: https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/MyHello/graphs/contributors

Comment: А в чем проблема? Что не так?

Comment: @Эникейщик я про проблему ничего не писал, хочу просто узнать почему я сам у себя в контрибьюторах?

Comment: На гитхабе не вы, а проект. Так что не у себя, а в проекте. Коммит сделал - контрибьютор. Что не так-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик в таком случае почему если я комичу с одного компютера, то я количество контрибьюторов равно 0? Вот что не так!

Comment: Ааа, а вот это уже совсем другой вопрос. Если посмотреть [историю коммитов](https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/MyHello/commits/master), то видно что там другой пользователь с таким же именем без ссылки. Скорее всего, у него в гите другие настройки (например, отсутствует имейл, т.к. на гитхабе идентификация делается по имейлу в профиле гита).

Comment: Т.е. на самом деле надо спрашивать, почему коммиты с первого компа не показываются в контрибьюторах.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, внесите, пожалуйста, правку, сформулировав именно то, что вас интересует, а не то, что **сейчас** написано в вопросе. либо, лучше удалите вопрос и задайте новый, с правильной формулировкой.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin немного подредактировал,такая формулировка устраивает?

Comment: Судя по всему, в контрибьюторах пишутся только зарегистрированные пользователи гитхаба. Аккаунты определяются по e-mail. Накоммитили с кривым емейлом - гитхаб вас не признал и в контрибьюторах не показал

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как делать коммиты от имени аккаунта GitHub?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849731)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> почему?

потому что, если посмотреть на историю коммитов:

```
$ git log -n 2 --format=format:'%ae'
andrejlevkivitch@gmail.com
andrejlevkovitch@gmail.com
```

то видно, что строка

```
andrejlevkivitch@gmail.com
```

не равна строке

```
andrejlevkovitch@gmail.com
```

разночтение — в одной букве в имени пользователя — <kbd>i</kbd> и <kbd>o</kbd>

---

p.s. а контрибуторы — это те пользователи github, от имени которых создавались коммиты (потому и нет информации про пользователя с неправильно написанным адресом — github не опознал его, как **своего** пользователя). и тот факт, что проект числится за вашей учётной записью, никак не отменяет вашей роли контрибьютора.