# Как сменить пользователя в git

Tags: github

Год назад создал и настроил аккаунт GitHub. Через некоторое время пришлось сменить создать новый. Когда пушу новый коммит в свой репозиторий, он загружается со старого аккаунта. Как исправить и заливать изменения с нового аккаунта?

Comment: Мб речь идет не про аккаунт, а про имя пользователя и почту, которые настраиваются в самом гите?

Comment: То ли связанный вопрос, то ли дубликат: [Как делать коммиты от имени аккаунта GitHub?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/849731)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как делать коммиты от имени аккаунта GitHub?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849731/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно всего лишь [почитать справку](https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user) и найти в ней ответ на вопрос. Коммиты приписываются тому аккаунту, который указан настройках репозитория на локальной машине. Нужно его изменить:

```
$ git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```