# Git на Github видит мои коммиты как от двух разных пользователей

Tags: git, github

Я добавляю коммиты через консоль в гитхаб, но активности нет (на самом сайте нет закрашенных зеленых квадратов).
Смотрю, а добавляю коммиты от двух своих аккаунтов.
Что случилось? Как мне это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: email у коммита не тот, что в показанных настройках

Comment: Да Вы правы! К Github подключено было две почты... 
Нужная была вторичной

Comment: @andreymal Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: Напишите в ответ, чтоб я принял

Comment: @nomnoms12 нет, потому что я не понимаю, что я такого особенного вообще написал

Comment: Ну и вообще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849731

Comment: @andreymal Ничего особенного для того, кто разбирается в устройстве GitHub :) А для остальных это очень хороший ответ. Я бы ещё добавил, что почта может быть любая, хоть Торвальдса, и GitHub свяжет её с соответствующей учётной записью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как [сказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219836/git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-github-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9?noredirect=1#comment2134180_1219836) @andreymal:

> У коммита должна быть такая же почта, как и у аккаунта GitHub