# Git указывает не верный ник при сommit

Tags: git, github

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мой ник Malfan, а тут какой-то другой юзер.

Comment: Оказывается nnnz7 - это мой забытый аккаунт, но как он подвязался к новому github?

Comment: [Как делать коммиты от имени аккаунта GitHub?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849731)

Comment: да, я кажется, нашел проблему. У меня в git config --list старая почта указана

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно было посмотреть какая почта прописана в git config --list, если не ваша, то смените её с помощью команды git config --global user.email "ваш емаил"